# Create B2C Policies via Graph API?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Can I create/update/delete policies via the [graph api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/)?

I've reviewed [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) and I don't see anything about policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No not yet, but we recently just started working on this capability.  If you are interested in helping us test this functionality when it eventually becomes available in preview, please send mail describing your scenario to AADB2CPreview@microsoft.com.  (we might have a private preview that we would need to enable on your test tenant specifically, or we might go straight to public preview)